# PgAdmin: Package 'pgAdmin4' has no installation candidate

Tags: ubuntu, pgadmin-4

I just installed PostgreSQL and I am trying to install pgdmin4, but whenever I run the command below to install pgadmin4 and pgadmin4-apache2

```
sudo apt install pgadmin4 pgadmin4-apache2
```

I often get the error

> E: Package 'pgadmin4' has no installation candidate
>
> E: Unable to locate package pgadmin4-apache2

I have tried out a lot of solutions, but none seems to do the trick. I need some help.

Comment: I voted to close this question because it is not about programming.  In the future, questions like this should be asked at [ubuntu.se].

Comment: There is also a site for database administration: [dba.se]

Answer (score 143, accepted):

**Here's how I solved the issue;**

The issue arises because the repository for pgadmin has not been added to your local machine.
To solve the issue, do the following below;

**Note**: This should work in Ubuntu 16.04 (Xenial), Ubuntu 18.04 (Bionic), Ubuntu 19.10 (Eoan), Ubuntu 20.04 (Focal), Debian 9 (Stretch) and Debian 10 (Buster) and possibly newer releases.

Install the public key for the repository (if not done previously):

```
curl https://www.pgadmin.org/static/packages_pgadmin_org.pub | sudo apt-key add
```

Create the repository configuration file:

```
sudo sh -c 'echo "deb https://ftp.postgresql.org/pub/pgadmin/pgadmin4/apt/$(lsb_release -cs) pgadmin4 main" > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/pgadmin4.list && apt update'
```

Choose the Installation method that you want:

- Install pgAdmin (**for both desktop and web modes**):

  ```
  sudo apt install pgadmin4
  ```
- Install pgAdmin (**for desktop mode only**):

  ```
  sudo apt install pgadmin4-desktop
  ```
- Install pgAdmin (**for web mode only**):

  ```
  sudo apt install pgadmin4-web
  ```

You can configure the webserver, **if you installed pgadmin for web mode**:

```
sudo /usr/pgadmin4/bin/setup-web.sh
```

**Resources**: [pgAdmin 4 (APT)](https://www.pgadmin.org/download/pgadmin-4-apt/)

Comment: I just upgraded from ubuntu 18.04 to 19.10 and my pgadmin got removed and when I tried to installed it by your way it's saying that  `Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.` Does that mean that pgadmin4 is not supported on ubuntu 19.10.

Comment: I have not tried installing Pgadmin4 on Ubuntu 19.10. I think you should check the supported operating systems on Pgadmin4's website to see if Ubuntu 19.10 is supported.

Comment: thanks for your response, I have installed it by 3rd party installation, pgAdmin3 package is availabe in 19.10 but not pgAdmin4.

Comment: As @Punnerud mentions in another ticket, for Ubuntu 18.04 you will have to sign the repo when adding it.

Comment: I am using ubuntu 18.04 LTS.The key which you mention helps me :
"sudo wget --quiet -O - https://www.postgresql.org/media/keys/ACCC4CF8.asc | sudo apt-key add -" not the complete one which i found in search with the problem.
Many thanks

Comment: I have modified my answer to allow for  Ubuntu 16.04 (Xenial), Ubuntu 18.04 (Bionic), Ubuntu 19.10 (Eoan), Ubuntu 20.04 (Focal), Debian 9 (Stretch) and Debian 10 (Buster) installations.

Comment: E: The repository 'https://ftp.postgresql.org/pub/pgadmin/pgadmin4/apt/n/a pgadmin4 Release' does not have a Release file.

this is what i am getting among other things on the second step. and the issue is still unsolved when i do apt install. I am trying to install this on parrot os(Debian 10)

Comment: currently not working with Linux Mint 20

Answer (score 47):

In my case, the following is working:

1st step:

```
curl https://www.pgadmin.org/static/packages_pgadmin_org.pub | sudo apt-key add
```

Create the repository configuration file. In the above answer, the command mentioned below is now too old and the page returns 404, so the packages will not be downloaded successfully.

```
sudo sh -c 'echo "deb https://ftp.postgresql.org/pub/pgadmin/pgadmin4/apt/$(lsb_release -cs) pgadmin4 main" > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/pgadmin4.list && apt update'
```

2nd step:

The updated and working command is:

```
sudo sh -c 'echo "deb https://ftp.postgresql.org/pub/pgadmin/pgadmin4/apt/focal/ pgadmin4 main" > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/pgadmin4.list && apt update'
```

3rd step:

```
sudo apt install pgadmin4
```

Comment: sudo apt-get install curl

Comment: ubuntu 21.04... only this answer works. Thanks!

Comment: This works in 22.04

Comment: this works for 20.04.2... Thanks.. still using old version

Comment: this answer work for me, linuxmint 20.3 cinnamon

Answer (score 7):

For Ubuntu 18.04 you have to add the Postgresql repository and key to apt:

```
wget --quiet -O - https://www.postgresql.org/media/keys/ACCC4CF8.asc | sudo apt-key add -
 sudo sh -c 'echo "deb http://apt.postgresql.org/pub/repos/apt/ `lsb_release -cs`-pgdg main" >> /etc/apt/sources.list.d/pgdg.list'
```

After this you have to run

```
sudo apt update
```

Then you can install, ex. with "sudo apt install pgadmin4 pgadmin4-apache2 -y"

Answer (score 3):

Run these Command bellow,

1. `sudo apt  install curl`
2. `curl https://www.pgadmin.org/static/packages_pgadmin_org.pub | sudo apt-key add`
3. `sudo sh -c 'echo "deb https://ftp.postgresql.org/pub/pgadmin/pgadmin4/apt/$(lsb_release -cs) pgadmin4 main" > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/pgadmin4.list && apt update'`
4. `sudo apt install pgadmin4`

You can also check [here](https://www.pgadmin.org/download/pgadmin-4-apt/).

Answer (score 1):

This has worked for me

```
sudo wget --quiet -O - https://www.postgresql.org/media/keys/ACCC4CF8.asc | sudo apt-key add -
sudo apt update
sudo apt install pgadmin4 pgadmin4-apache2
```

Answer (score 1):

```sh
sudo sh -c 'echo "deb http://apt.postgresql.org/pub/repos/apt/ $(lsb_release -cs)-pgdg main" >> /etc/apt/sources.list.d/pgdg.list'

sudo apt install wget ca-certificates

wget --quiet -O - https://www.postgresql.org/media/keys/ACCC4CF8.asc | sudo apt-key add

sudo apt update

sudo apt install pgadmin4
```

try this, I found it on : https://o7planning.org/11353/install-pgadmin-on-ubuntu#a6605357

and it worked, despite people saying there is no support for 20.04 (focal)

Answer (score 0):

The issue arises because the repository for `pgadmin` has not been added to your local machine. To solve the issue, do the following below;

Open your terminal and enter the command below

`sudo nano /etc/apt/sources.list.d/pgdg.list`

When `nano` editor opens up, copy and paste the line below into it

`deb http://apt.postgresql.org/pub/repos/apt/ focal-pgdg main`

then copy and paste this thing

`wget --quiet -O - https://www.postgresql.org/media/keys/ACCC4CF8.asc | sudo apt-key add -`

After that copy and paste this thing

`sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install pgadmin4`

Congratulations your job is done

Answer (score 0):

Import the repository key from https://www.postgresql.org/media/keys/ACCC4CF8.asc

```
curl https://www.postgresql.org/media/keys/ACCC4CF8.asc | gpg --dearmor | sudo tee /etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/apt.postgresql.org.gpg >/dev/null
```

Create `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/pgdg.list`.

```
sudo sh -c 'echo "deb http://apt.postgresql.org/pub/repos/apt $(lsb_release -cs)-pgdg main" > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/pgdg.list'
```

Finally, update the package lists, and start installing packages:

```
sudo apt update
```

Provide the web interface accessible in a web browser:

```
sudo apt install pgadmin4-web
```

Provide desktop application for Ubuntu system, which required Ubuntu Desktop system:

```
sudo apt install pgadmin4-desktop
```

Install both, web and desktop:

```
sudo apt install pgadmin4
```

References: https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Apt

Comment: your answer worked for my Ubuntu 18.04

Comment: not working, E: Package 'pgadmin4' has no installation candidate.

Answer (score 0):

### I was facing same issue. However I am able to resolve it by following below instructions :

1. Visit : https://www.postgresql.org/ftp/pgadmin/pgadmin4/snapshots/
2. select latest directory by date [image]
3. select folder name : **apt** [image]
4. Follow instructions given in Readme.md file [image]

---

Event after following above instructions if you're not able to install pgadmin4 on ubuntu23.04, then :

```
In step 2, select different directory by date & follow same instructions.
```

### Note:

> I am able to install pgadmin4 v7.8 on ubuntu 23.04 by selecting
> 2023-11-09 directory in step 2 & then following rest insturctions.

All the best!

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to open

`/etc/apt/sources.list.d/pgadmin4.list`

replace una with focal.

[Blog post with the solution.](https://www.serveradminblog.com/2023/03/the-repository-does-not-have-a-release-file-pgadmin4-on-mint-linux/)

Answer (score 0):

Working as of 31 December 2023

1. `curl https://www.pgadmin.org/static/packages_pgadmin_org.pub | sudo apt-key add`
2. `sudo sh -c 'echo "deb https://ftp.postgresql.org/pub/pgadmin/pgadmin4/apt/$(lsb_release -cs) pgadmin4 main" > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/pgadmin4.list && apt update'`
3. Updated command (100% working tested on ubuntu)
   `sudo sh -c 'echo "deb https://ftp.postgresql.org/pub/pgadmin/pgadmin4/apt/focal/ pgadmin4 main" > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/pgadmin4.list && apt update'`
4. `sudo apt install pgadmin4`